# The LORD dwells in a dark cloud or thick cloud in 1 Kings 8:12?

Tags: 1-kings

1 Kings 8:12
New International Version

> Then Solomon said, "The LORD has said that he would dwell in a **dark** cloud;

dark cloud
בָּעֲרָפֶֽל׃ (bā·‘ă·rā·p̄el)
Preposition-b, Article | Noun - masculine singular
Strong's Hebrew 6205: Cloud, **heavy** cloud

In https://biblehub.com/matthew/20-16.htm, 21 versions use the word "dark" to translate this verse. 4 versions use "thick" and did not use the word "dark". Some use both.

New American Standard Bible

> Then Solomon said, "The LORD has said that He would dwell in the **thick** cloud.

New Living Translation

> Then Solomon prayed, “O LORD, you have said that you would live in a **thick** cloud of **darkness**.

Which is the most appropriate?

Comment: Does the density of the cloud obscure light ? Or is the 'cloud' a 'darkness' in and of itself ? +1

Comment: Precisely, I couldn't have said it better myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hebrew does not have a separate word (thick or dark) acting as an adjective modifying "cloud".  Instead there is a single word, עֲרָפֶל (araphel) which occurs just 15 times in the OT: Ex 20:21, 4;11, 5:22, 2 Sam 22;10, 1 Kings 8:12, 2 Chron 6:1, Job 22:13, 38:9, Ps 18:9, 97:2, Isa 60:2, Jer 13:16, Eze 34:12, Joel 2:2, Zeph 1:15.

The BDB listed meaning is:

> עֲרָפֶל noun masculine cloud, heavy cloud (perhaps from above √ + ל
> afformative; Late Hebrew = Biblical Hebrew; Syriac ; ᵑ7 עֲרָפֵילָא;
> Mandean ארפילא NöM 126, 128; on vocaliz. see BaNB 160 and against him
> SchwZAW x (1890), 178 who proposes עַרְמֶּל); — ׳ע in which God dwells
> Exodus 20:18 (Gi; van d. H. Exodus 20:21), 1 Kings 8:12 2 Chronicles
> 6:1; + עָנָן Deuteronomy 4:11 (also חשֶׁח), Deuteronomy 5:19; Psalm
> 97:2; Job 22:13 see בַּעַד; תַּחַת רַגְלָיו ׳ע 2 Samuel 22:10 = Psalm
> 18:10; as swaddling-bands of sea Job 38:9; figurative of misery Isaiah
> 60:2 ("" חשֶׁח); of ׳יs judgment Jeremiah 13:16 ("" צַלְמָוֶת), as a
> past day ׳יוֺם עָנָן וַע Ezekiel 34:12 = (of future day of ׳י)
> Zephaniah 1:15 ("" יוֺם חשֶׁח וַאֲפֵלָה) = Joel 2:2 ("" id.).

Thus, the meaning is clear - it is a thick, heavy cloud that either obscures light, or, creates gloom, eg, Deut 4:11, 5:22, etc, depending on the context.

In 1 Kings 8:12, this makes the meaning easy to determine.  The thick heavy cloud obscures the visage of the the LORD but does not necessarily imply darkness.  On the contrary, we find in 1 John 1:5 -

> And this is the message we have heard from Him and announce to you:
> God is light, and in Him there is no darkness at all.

Thus, I understand the thick cloud ensures that God remains unseen (John 1:18), but not in darkness.